# Binary Search For an Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

My Binary search keeps returning zero I'm not sure why. Maybe I'm passing my arguments in incorrectly? Or maybe I'm not returning it right? I'm not quite sure what is wrong, if anyone could explain how I can return the values I want instead of zero thanks. my array  is filled with words I didn't include that part of my code because it is being filled in by a file. I'm not entering the first word so I shouldnt be getting zero. I've tried multiple words.

```
     using namespace std;
     #include <iostream>
     #include <fstream>
     #include <string>


     //function prototypes
     void selectionSort(string[], int);
     int binarySearch(string[], int, string);

     int main()
  {
int open;
int name[8];
ifstream inputFile;
string filename;
int i = 0;
int size = 1024;
int newSize;
string exit;
string words[1024];
string word;
string newArray[1024];
string search;
int results;
string createdFile;
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;
//newArray[0]="This";


cout << "Please Enter the Filename: ";
cin >> filename;
inputFile.open(filename.c_str());
if (!inputFile) {
    cout << "Your File could not be opened!";
}
else if (inputFile) {

    while (i<1024) {
        inputFile >> word;
        //cout << i;
        if (word.length()<2) {              //gets rid of single character words
        i++;
        }
        else if(inputFile.eof()) {
        //cout<<newSize<<endl;
        newSize=i;
        //cout<< "DONE!"<<newSize;
        break;
        }
        else{
        newArray[i] = word;
        i++;
        //cout<<newArray[i]<<" " ;
        //newSize=1;



        //cout<<newSize;
        }

        //cout << newArray;
        //i++;
    }




}
inputFile.close();
//Take values stored in array and put them in another array with i number of elements

    string finalArray[i];
    size=i;
    for(int j = 0; j<i;j++)
        {
        finalArray[j]=newArray[j];

        //cout<<finalArray[j];
        }

cout << "Your document has been sorted. " << endl;
selectionSort(finalArray, size);
cout<< "Out putting Your array"<<endl;
for (int z = 0; z<size; z++) {
    cout << finalArray[z] << " ";
}

    cout << "Please insert a word to search!: " << endl;
    cin >> search;
    results = binarySearch(finalArray, size, search);
    cout << results << endl;
    //results = binarySearch(finalArray, size, search);
    //cout << results;
    cout << "To exit press 0, or enter another word..." << endl;



}//end of main


   void selectionSort(string array[], int size) {
int startScan, minIndex;
string minValue;

for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];
    for (int index = startScan + 1; index <size; index++) {
        if (array[index]<minValue) {
            minValue = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minValue;

}
   }


   int binarySearch(string words[], int numElems, string word) {

int first = 0,                 //first array element
    last = numElems - 1,            //last array element
    middle,                        //mid point of search
    position = -1;                 //position of search value
bool found = false;            //flag

while (!found && first == last)
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2; //this finds the mid point
    if (words[middle] == word) {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if (words[middle]> word) // if it's in the lower half
    {
        last = middle - 1;
    }
    else {
        first = middle + 1;                 //if it's in the upper half
    }
    return position;

     }
   }//end binarySearch
```

Comment: You haven't filled in the array, and you haven't input `search`.

Comment: You're aware that you have an array of fifteen empty strings?

Comment: This isnt the full code I have the array filled with words

Comment: Then show real code. Code which **reproduces** error. For example, are words in your array sorted?

Comment: @Barmar I just forgot to include when copying and pasting. but I am searching for a word for example 'the' and it's somewhere in the middle of the array. However it still returns zero.

Comment: Some hints: Think for a few minutes about when `!found && first == last` is true. Consider the starting values for `first` and `last` when you pass in the size 15. Also look at the placement of the `return` in the function and consider its consequences.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks for the tip I have included the whole code.

Comment: @Y3DII: Can you please format it nicely?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you very much for your insight, this really did help. I appreciated your hints very much so. It helped me really think about my problem, and the hints were just enough to help me make connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `return position;` inside the `while` loop, but not in any of the `if/else` blocks, so it returns after the first iteration even when it hasn't yet found the search string. You should move that to after the loop, or do it in the `if` block that sets `position` when it finds a matching element.

Another problem is that the `while` condition is true. You want to keep looping while `first` is **not** equal to `last`. Actually, that's not the right condition, either, because if the array only has one element, `first` and `last` will always be equal, and you'll stop before you test whether it matches. So the correct test is `while (first <= last)`.

```
int binarySearch(string words[], int numElems, string word) 
{
    int first = 0,                 //first array element
    last = numElems - 1,            //last array element
    middle;                        //mid point of search

    while (first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2; //this finds the mid point
        if (words[middle] == word) {
            return middle;
        }
        else if (words[middle]> word) // if it's in the lower half
        {
            last = middle - 1;
        }
        else {
            first = middle + 1;                 //if it's in the upper half
        }
    }
    return -1;  // not found
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, you were indeed correct and my problem was fixed.